# How to match an array of strings in location directive?

Tags: nginx

I want to go inside a location section whenever the url matches not just one string, but any among a list of strings.

Something like:

```
location ['one', 'two', 'three'] {
    # do more stuff
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

you can do so by using a regex location:

```
location ~ "^/(one|two|three)/.*" {
  #do your stuff
}
```

NOTE: use `~*` instead of `~` if you want case-insensitive matching